# freemarker date check (freemarker.template.SimpleScalar)

Tags: validation, freemarker

I am trying to find if a transaction date is less than or equal to 8 days in the past to pass through a module.

```
<#assign FIRST_STARTDATE = dayadd(.now, -8)?string("yyyy-MM-dd")>

<#if EXTENDED.FIRST_TRANS_DT lte FIRST_STARTDATE>

yes.module

<#else>

No.module

</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what does "8 days in the past" precisely mean, it's perhaps sufficient if you get the milliseconds since the epoch with `.now?long`, and you apply `?long` on the other date too. Then you can get the distance between the two in milliseconds with a subtraction. If the other date is in fact a string, then you have to convert it to a real date first (see `?date` or `?datetime`). Converting a date to a string is almost never the good direction, if you want to do anything with it other than printing.

Finally, "8 days in the past" often means some calendar arithmetic instead, in which case it's probably best to be externalized to Java code.

Comment: I'm trying to find if FIRST_STARTDATE in a table has occurred within the last 8 days. If it has then I will pull in the designated module, if it has not it will go to the next if statement.